# Spring boot Jsp / Tag in different module

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

I'm trying to achieve the following:

- Webapp module which contains default Spring boot classes from the https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp sample. The sample itself works correctly.
- Shared module which contains jsp tld and tag to be used in the webapp module.

If the tag files are located in the webapp module it correctly shows the tag. If the tag files are located in the shared module the tld file is found but the custom.tag cannot be found with exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: File [/WEB-INF/tags/custom.tag] not found
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:55) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:293) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:80) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.parseTagFileDirectives(TagFileProcessor.java:499) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.createTagFileInfo(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:328) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:204) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:431) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:489) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1445) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:144) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:105) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:350) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:595) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:304) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.20.RELEASE.jar:4.3.20.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

This it the testproject: https://github.com/Gunthervg/spring-boot-jsp-tags => SampleWebJspApplicationTests does also fail because of this.

Someone knows how I could fix this issue?

Edit: 
Possible related to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8324

Comment: maybe you should write a maven command to copy custom.tag from shared module to /WEB-INF/tags/custom.tag

Comment: @Spara Yeah that would be possible, but then again if I want to run in in an IDE i always have to run maven or do some other magic to make it work.

Comment: In intelliJ you can add maven task before run the project

Comment: @Spara True but that makes it cumbersome and slow, I would rather see it working without copying files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

- Moved tags from src/main/resources/META-INF/tags to src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/tags according to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8324.
- Changed packaging to war

Use maven-war-plugin which includes the tags and places them under /WEB-INF:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>../shared/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources</directory>
                        </resource>                 
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```